# How soon will SQL Server reach capacity at this rate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am moving from MS Access to SQL Server, yay! I know that SQL Server has a huge capacity over of 500k Terabytes, but I have also been told by my boss that SQL Server will eventually not be able to handle the rate I am inserting into my tables.

I have a table with 64 columns and each day around ~20,000 rows are added (1.28 million cells). The majority (~70%) of the data types are strings of on average 16 characters long. The rest of the data types are short numbers or booleans. 
I am tracking financial data, which is why there is so much. The assumption is that this data will need to be tracked into perpetuity, if not at least 3-5 years.

So at this rate, will SQL Server be able to handle my data? Will I have to do some special configuration to get it to work, or is this amount laughably minuscule? I feel like its enough but I just want to make sure before moving forward.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm going for 'laughably miniscule', but not in a horrible way. Think your design through and choose appropriate data types and you should be fine for decades.

Comment: Do you have a primary key: is this such that data will only ever be appended? Are there many other indexes to be maintained?

Comment: I have no primary key, it is a logging table. When I do need to match, I match on a concatenation of 2 ID fields.

Comment: Is this all you're using SQL Server for? This one logging table which is just a raw heap? If so (or there's no direct relationship between other data you're storing in SQL Server), you may be better served with a "NoSQL" datastore - Azure DocumentDB, MongoDB, Hadoop, Elastic/logstash, etc.

Comment: Not just a raw heap as the logging table will JOIN with another table to get a historical view of changes made to a certain item. I have considered a noSQL datastore but thats more of an issue of management approval.

Comment: Your insert rate is low and I'm guessing the read rate will be important. You may want to cluster an index on the columns that will be used for the joins.

Comment: Don't literally match on a concatenation of 2.  Where id1 = x and id2 = y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has less to do with `sql server` and more to do with the box it's running on. How big is the hard drive? How much memory is in there? What kind of CPU is sitting on it? 20000 a day isn't so much, even with wide varchar(). But without good indexing, partitioning, and the memory, disk space and CPU to handle queries against it, your problem  is more likely to be slow performing queries.

At any rate, assuming you are using `VARCHAR()` instead of `NVARCHAR()` a single character is a byte. You say they average 16, but is that the length of the string stored in the `VARCHAR()` or the max size of the `VARCHAR()`? It will make a difference.

Assuming that's the average string length of a field, then you can do `64x16` to understand the byte size of a record (not super dooper accurate because of the need for meta data, but close enough). That would be `1024` bytes or `1kb` per record.

After 5 years that would be `20000*365*5` which is `36,500,000kb` which is `36.5gb`. No biggie. Add indexing on there and metadata and all that, and maybe you'll be pushing `50gb` for this table.

My guess is that your average string length is less than 16 though and that the fields are just defined as `VARCHAR(16)`. `VARCHAR()` only stores as many bytes as the length of the string (plus 2 to define the length), so it's probably less than this estimate. If the table is defined with all `CHAR(16)` then the storage will always be 16 bytes.

Also, if you are storing unicode and using `NVARCHAR()` then double all the calculations since SQL Server uses UTF8 which is 2 bytes per character.

Answer (score 1):

**Very** rough, back-of-the-envelope calculations:

- 16 bytes per field
- 64 fields per record
- 20,000 records per day

You're adding 20MB per day to the table. 7GB per year.

This is not a large amount of data. There are many people running multi-terabyte databases on SQL Server.

What's more important is the process by which you load the data into the table, your indexing (so that you can efficiently query the data), server configuration (I/O, memory, CPU) and how you're managing it all. Eventually, you may need Enterprise Edition to make use of additional memory, table partitioning, etc.

The short answer to your question: yes, SQL Server can handle this just fine, as long as you design it properly

Answer (score 0):

If I count just the data:

```
20.000 rows * (70% * 16 bytes + 30% * 4 bytes) * 64 columns = 15.872.000 bytes.
```

You are inserting 16 MB per day. That is going to last a long time before it becomes unmanagable.

Answer (score 0):

At this rate, by the time you get even **close** to capacity, there will be newer versions of SQL Server, and newer server hardware, and newer other technologies that will be able to handle your increased needs.

So don't worry about it.